# trigger event on disabled HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea element on which I wan't to fire an event.
When setting up a listener and the element is disabled I get an inconsistent behavior. Chrome (64.0.3282.186), Safari (11.0.3) and Edge fires the event and everything looks good (as I would expect them to do) but in Firefox (58.0.2) the eventlistener does not fire.
Anyone got any idea on how to solve this without enabling the element?

```js
var eventName = 'bar',
    element = document.querySelector('#foo'),
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, {
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: false,
        detail: null
    });

element.addEventListener(eventName, function() {
    element.value = 'X';
});
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<textarea id="foo" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `HTMLElement` method that enables the element, dispatches the event and then disables it again afterwards.

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.fireEvent = function(e) {
    const isDisabled = this.hasAttribute('disabled');
    
    this.removeAttribute('disabled');
    this.dispatchEvent(e);
  
    if (isDisabled)
        this.setAttribute('disabled', true);
};

var eventName = 'bar',
    element = document.querySelector('#foo'),
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, {
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: false,
        detail: null
    });

element.addEventListener(eventName, function() {
    element.value = 'X';
});

element.fireEvent(event)
```

```html
<textarea id="foo" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Granted, this modifies the native element which is frowned upon - you can avoid prototype methods and just write a plain old function, i.e `fireEvent(elem, event)`.

Comment: Of course I could do that, but that is just a hack to get around the problem. If I find no other way to get around this then I will of course fallback to a solution similar to this, but for now I look for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I fully agree but the MDN docs for the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) attribute make no mention of `CustomEvents` behavior which leads me to believe that they just blanket-disabled all events with no way around it through configuration. Good luck though.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an bug to Mozilla on the matter as nothing is mentioned in the w3 spec that the element should **not** dispatch events when the element is disabled.

The only thing that is mentioned is that mouse events should not be dispatched.
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fe-disabled

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

The bug can be found here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1443148